# Check-in using GitHub

Tags: github

I am checking out code using GitHub client for Windows. When I press "clone" button in browser, it looks like I have a local copy. However, there are a few files that GitHub is asking me to commit. Now, I have not even made any changes to anything on my local. So why is it asking me to "commit"?

Can anyone tell me why I am facing this problem. Also, are there any good GitHub tutorials to follow?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what are the files it is asking you to commit?

Comment: apparently, these files are source code Java files which seem to have some difference with that found on repository.I don't want to press "commit" just in case I end up screwing up company's code :(

Comment: If you look at the differences in the client, does it give you a clue as to where the difference came from? Maybe you opened them in an IDE and it changed the formatting?

Comment: naa...i did not open it in any IDE.My only question is whether you should make your Git Hub directory your working directory? Where should I make changes to project and from where should I commit and push changes to repository?

Comment: the directory you chose to clone to is the working directory. And if you have done a clone into a clean directory and done nothing else then there should be no files that are being shown as changed files to commit.

Comment: honestly,this is what surprises me.I cloned it into a clean directory and my working directory is different.Don't understand why I am getting these conflicts.Can you tell how to change the directory to clone project to?

Answer (score 0):

There is a great github tutorial here, that should get you started with the basics: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/.